# MKAnnotation constructor error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm having a problem with MKAnnotation, i created a class "cgdMapAnnotation" for annotations and one of it's constructor is like this:

```
+ (id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate andTitle:(NSString*) title andSubtitle:(NSString*) subtitle {
    self = [super alloc];
    _coordinate = coordinate;
    _title = [title retain];
    _subtitle = [subtitle retain];
    return self;
}
```

The problem is that when i call:

```
cgdMapAnnotation *placemark=[[[cgdMapAnnotation alloc]    initWithCoordinate:centerCoordinate andTitle:@"Title" andSubtitle:@"SubTitle" ] autorelease];
```

I get in the console the following error:

```
-[cgdMapAnnotation initWithCoordinate:andTitle:andSubtitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x33cf2fe0
```

I really don't understand what's the problem. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convention has it that class names start with a capital letter.  So cgdMapAnnotation should be CgdMapAnnotation or CGDMapAnnotation.

Second, there are a few problems with initWithCoordinate:andTitle:andSubtitle:.

- It is declared as a class method using the '+' at the beginning of the name, but you are attempting to use it as an instance method.  [cgdMapAnnotation alloc] will return an instance of cgdMapAnnotation.  So you are
- self = [super alloc] does not make sense in this class method.

Your method should probably look like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoodinate2D)coordinate andTitle:(NSString*) title andSubtitle:(NSString*) subtitle
{
  if( self = [super init] )
  {
    _coordinate = coordinate;
    _title = [title retain];
    _subtitle = [subtitle retain];
  }

  return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. It's my first iPhone project, so stil a newbie. By the way, what's the difference between a "-" and a "+" in a class method?

Comment: "+" indicates a class method, so it can be called on the class object. UIButton's buttonWithType is an example.  So you call [UIButton buttonWithType:TYPE].  "-" indicates an instance method, so it is called on an instance of a class.  An example there is UIButton's imageForState.  So you would call [someButton imageForState:STATE].